# Rails asset pipeline & coffeescript files, how to bind actions in various files to ajax calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

Using rails 3 asset pipeline, I've structured the javascript (by using coffeescript) to files regarding the model. For example, all comment writing related javascript is stored to /app/assets/javascripts/comments.js.coffee, and user overlay related (fetching a:href's and triggering ajax on them) are stored in /app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee.

However, now I'm using more and more AJAX calls, where HTML content is pulled dynamically to the site. The problem is that I need to execute the javascript in various files, but as coffeescript is scoped inside a function, I can not access them.

Let's say that I've got a general.js.coffee file with following code

```
$(document).ready ->
  # Parse all images with action
  $("img.clickableaction").click ->
    # Fetch some content
    $.ajax
      url: "something.php"
      dataType: "html"
      complete: (xhr, status) ->
        # We got the content, set it up to a container
        $("#somecontainer").html(receiveddata)

        # The tricky part:

        # run code in comments.js.coffee for #somecontainer (or for the whole dom)
        # run code in users.js.coffee for #somecontainer (or for the whole dom)
```

And comments.js.coffee contains for example the following:

```
$(document).ready ->
  commentDiv = $('div#commentsContainer')
  commentsFetch = $('a.commentsFetch')

  # Set commentid for comments fetch
  commentsFetch.bind 'ajax:beforeSend', (event, xhr, settings) ->
    # do stuff
```

The comments.js.coffee code works for the initial page view, e.g. the HTML code that was received when user loaded the page. But now, I need to parse the comments.js.coffee code for the content returned from the ajax call.

I can not make a function inside comments.js because it is scoped away, and can not be accessed from the general.js. This is what coffeescript produces:

```
(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var commentDiv, commentsFetch;
    commentDiv = $('div#commentsContainer');
    commentsFetch = $('a.commentsFetch');
  }
})
```

I *could* make a global function for each separate file, e.g. window.comments && window.users, but then I'd need to call window.comments from the many places where I need to have ajax oncomplete call. On the long term, that will produce duplicate and hard to maintain -code.

How could something like this be made:

```javascript
// comments.js
window.ajaxExecuteBlocks.push(function() { // comments related stuff });

// user.js
window.ajaxExecuteBlocks.push(function() { // user related stuff });

// general.js ajax on complete:
window.runExecuteBlocks()
```

Then, runExecuteBlocks would somehow run through all the functions that have been initialized in various controller-specific javascript files.

Anyone implemented similar system?